# How to do input textes from textfield to html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

To see my problem please click on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxjdz/).

When you want to add text the textfield got visible. Then you type something and click one or two times on the canvas the text got visible. When you change to text and click again another text got visible **AND THE OLD ONE CHANGES :(** And thats the problem.

**Description:**

I use the [sketch.js](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) where you can draw some stuff and erase it.
My idea was e.g. to add text to the canvas.
So i added a new tool to the tools-bar:

```
<a href="#tools_sketch" data-tool="text">Text</a>
```

Then i added a textfield which get visible when you click the text-tool.

```
function setVisible () {
    document.getElementById("div_for_textfield").style.display="block";
}
function setNotVisible () {
    document.getElementById("div_for_textfield").style.display="none";
}
```

So far, so good.

In the sketch.js, i writed a new tool "text" which take the value from the textfield and add it to the canvas:

```
var text = document.getElementById("textfield_for_text_tool").value;
this.context.fillText(text, event.x, event.y);
```

Did anyone knew what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks everyone for reading!

**Edit:** I just created another fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rjAUa/ with the example from http://oldstatic.travisberry.com/demos/canvas-text-demo/index.html and the answer from [Add multiple instances of text to an HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950731/add-multiple-instances-of-text-to-an-html5-canvas?rq=1) - the problem now is that when i leave the canvas the text is not saved.
The problem is the sketch.js what i use. How can i write the text tool without using the sketch.js?

Comment: Yes this works. The whole thing works. see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxjdz/). The problem is that the text of the old ones changes when i input a new one. I can only have one content for multiple textes :/

Comment: Here is a picture which describe the problem better: [click](http://s7.directupload.net/images/140716/5qiyg5mh.png)

Comment: `var text = elements[i].value; this.context.fillText(text, event.x, event.y);` --> reset the content && `this.context.fillText(event.x, event.x, event.y);` --> do not reset the content